# Setting height, and width of an image from vars in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an image as my background and fit the browser's dimensions. However, I get: `expmrt.html:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of null`.

```js
//Get the browser legth and height, then after the code is done, time out in 300 miliseconds.
function ScreenLoop() {
  var Width = window.innerWidth;
  var Height = window.innerHeight;
  alert("Width: " + Width + " and also Height: " + Height) //Debugging reasons
  document.getElementById("theimage").width = Width; // Where the error: expmrt.html:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of null) occures for some reason.
  document.getElementById("theimage").height = Height;
  setTimeout(ScreenLoop(), 300);
};
ScreenLoop();
```

```html
<img src="tl2fZkc.png" id="theimage" width="50" height="50" alt="theimage" />
```

Comment: Try `element.style.width= Value+'px'` And write your script before closing body tag...`</body>`

Comment: To call setTimeout you need to pass a function to it or a string, so you need `setTimeout(ScreenLoop, 300);`

Comment: So i just use:
<img src="tl2fZkc.png" id="theimage" width="50" height="50" alt="theimage" element.style.width= Width+'px'/> 
@RayonDabre

Comment: @LeeIkard You must make sure the javascript executes after the DOM has been loaded.. So take the advice from Rayon Dabre or Chris Benseler :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call ScreenLoop() inside the load event from the window

```
window.onload = function() {
   ScreenLoop();
}
```